# C code that gives this error how can I fix

Tags: c

```
#include <unistd.h>

void ft_putchar(char c)
{
    write(1, &c, 1);
}
```

This code gives this error

```
/rbin/ld: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/crt1.o: in function `_start':
(.text+0x20): undefined reference to `main' collect2: error: ld
returned 1 exit status
```

Comment: Your program needs a `main` function by definition.

Comment: What environment are you using to build your application? How do you build your application? Is there a source file with a `main` function somewhere?

Comment: And you *do* know that all C programs need a `main` function?

Comment: It's not the compiler that minds - it might be one of several modules. The `ld` shows it to be a linker error. As stated, there must be exactly one `main` function somewhere.

Answer (score 0):

The error it reported is precisely what you need to know and pay attention to.

```
undefined reference to `main'
```

Its a linker error, reported when linker tries to find but fails to locate a `main()` function, which is usually the entry-point function of a program.

There can be two situations here:

1. Your source code is incomplete, it doesn't have the implementation of `main` function.
2. During compilation, you are not including the source file which has `main`, hence the linker cannot see it.

Your code needs to have exactly one implementation of `main()` function.  If you can't find it any of the relevant modules, implementing it will solve the problem at hand.

Comment: The posted source code implements one of the functions of a library. It is not meant to be linked as a stand alone program.